# Correlation via primary key column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with unequal rows of data that I need to correlate with via "3rd-party" column. This 3rd-party column is a DATETIME primary key for both tables.

Here are the tables

```
|XKey       |XColumn            |
|-------------------------------|
|2012-01-00 |0.17
|2012-02-00 |0.24
|2012-03-00 |0.33
|2012-04-00 |0.41
|--------------------------------




Y TABLE
=======

|YKey       |YColumn            |
|-------------------------------|
|2012-01-01 |0.21
|2012-01-15 |0.12
|2012-02-01 |0.26
|2012-02-15 |0.27
|2012-03-01 |0.14
|2012-03-15 |0.11
|2012-04-01 |0.74
|2012-04-15 |0.66
|2012-05-01 |0.14
|--------------------------------
```

The values in y table should correlate to corresponding values in the x table whose xkey value is less than or equal to the respective ykey values.

This prepared statement is simply yielding null! What could I be overlooking?

```
SET @sql_run =  CONCAT(
        'SET @correl = (SELECT (1/(?-1))*SUM(((a.'
        ,XColumn
        ,' - ?)/?)*((b.'
        ,YColumn
        ,' - ?)/?)) FROM '
        ,XTable
        ,' a JOIN '
        ,YTable
        ,' b ON a.'
        ,XKey
        ,' <= b.'
        ,YKey
        ,' GROUP BY a.'
        ,XKey
        ,', b.'
        ,YKey
        ,' HAVING COUNT(a.'
        ,XKey
        ,') < 2 ORDER BY a.'
        ,XKey
        ,', b.'
        ,YKey
        ,')'
        );      
PREPARE statement_run FROM @sql_run ;
EXECUTE statement_run USING @num, @x_avg, @x_std, @y_avg, @y_std ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement_run ;
```

Having adjuusted the date values in xtable am now getting the error 'subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: what input variables are passed? - can you show a completed sql statement with variables in place?

Comment: These are the input variables which are set prior to nuber of rows, average and standard deviation... the error am getting now is subquery returns more than one value

Comment: `@num, @x_avg, @x_std, @y_avg, @y_std`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XKey date values are invalid. Try setting them to the first of the month instead of 0.

Comment: I just tried adding a date value and now am getting an error the subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Start by running the query with known values (IE not in a prepared statement). The format you're using is hard (for me) to read. It looks like you're trying to assign multiple rows to one @variable (@correl).

Comment: Got it to work finally `  SET @sql_run =  CONCAT(
    'SET @correl = (SELECT (1/(?-1))*SUM(((c.x1 - ?)/?)*((c.y1 - ?)/?)) FROM (SELECT b.'
    ,YKey
    ,', a.'
    ,XColumn
    ,' AS x1, b.'
    ,YColumn
    ,' AS y1 FROM '
    ,XTable
    ,' a JOIN '
    ,YTable
    ,' b ON a.'
    ,XKey
    ,' >= b.'
    ,YKey
    ,' GROUP BY b.'
    ,YKey
    ,') AS c)'
    );`